# How do I access a key:value pair from an object that is inside of an array?

Tags: arrays, object

> I have some saved data that I am trying to display onto a line graph in Chartjs.

> The problem is, I am having trouble accessing the empty ‘data’ array from the initial state because it is structured as such:

```
const [chartData, setData] = useState({
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'My Overall Progress',
        data: [],
        fill: true,
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        tension: 0.1,
      },
    ],
  });
```

> I am not quite sure how to access the empty data array from the initial state because it is inside of an object inside of an array.

Answer (score 1):

you can access the data array by using

```
chartData.datasets[0].data
```